# Sitecore analytics is not working after doing changes in IIS Url Rewrite Module

Tags: experience-analytics, redirect

Client wanted to have a trailing slash at the end of urls and it should be redirected with 301. I have configured in IIS Url Rewrite and It is working fine as expected but I am getting an issue in the Analytics Tracker as below

[image]

Sitecore version :: 9

Has anyone come across this issue? Kindly give your suggestions

Note: Sitecore experience editor is keep loading after these changes. I have tried installing sitecore rewrite module which breaks the sitecore instance.

Comment: Can you add your rewrite rule? It is possible to add conditions to it, to avoid redirect of certain URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the error above, it looks like you are rewriting too many URL formats. Your client likely wanted folders (like "www.example.com/about-us") rewritten to have trailing slashes, not all file names.

File paths like .htm, .aspx, .css, etc. should not usually be rewritten in this way. It breaks the file extension.

Comment: Thanks Jay. Is that possible to have rewrite rules only for sitecore pages. I mean content tree along with sub items. As you said, this rule is so generic which is causing the issue.

Comment: I don't think that's what your client is trying to do. They are likely trying to enforce canonical usage via rewrite rules so that there are not multiple versions of URLs. I would suggest you clarify what your customer wants to do as a goal so that you can solution properly.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have next rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Force trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*[^/])" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

You have to add conditions to avoid redirection of URL that are paths that should not be redirected (paths to files or specific Sitecore paths):

```
<rule name="Force trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*[^/])" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^.*\.css$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^.*\.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^.*\.js$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^.*\.ashx$" ignoreCase="true" />
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^sitecore.*\.js$" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}/" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```